# Fluid Page Templates: backend layout doesn't change

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I've followed https://fluidtypo3.org/documentation/templating-manual/templating/creating-templates/page-template.html to create an extension holding all my templates and layouts. I's working fine exept my backend layout doesn't change to the grid layout I've defined in my template:

```
  {namespace vhs=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}
  {namespace flux=FluidTYPO3\Flux\ViewHelpers}

  <f:layout name="Default" />

  <f:section name="Configuration">
     <flux:form id="Default" label="Homepage">
        <flux:grid>
           <flux:grid.row>
              <flux:grid.column colPos="0" name="Content" label="Main content" />
              <flux:grid.column colPos="1" name="Sidebar" label="Sidebar" />
           </flux:grid.row>
        </flux:grid>
     </flux:form>
  </f:section>


  <f:section name="Main">
  <div id="main_content">
     <vhs:content.render column="0" />
  </div>
  <div id="aside">
     <vhs:content.render column="1" />
  </div>
  </f:section>
```

I've selected this template in the "page layouts" tab, but the layout is the default 4-grid-layout. Did I forget something?

my setup.txt:

```
plugin.tx_myext.view {
    templateRootPath = EXT:tx_myext/Resources/Private/Templates/
    partialRootPath = EXT:tx_myext/Resources/Private/Partials/
    layoutRootPath = EXT:tx_myext/Resources/Private/Layouts/    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

had the same problem.

**Solution**:
Edit root page -> Appearance tab -> Backend Layout -> Fluidpages

Comment: Uff... you have to select "fluidpages" in the appearance tab additionally to the Page Layout... sry, I've overseen that.